# Stylesheet Not rending in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

Wordpress is not loading my CSS file. Stylesheet has one item on it that centers the header image, but it won't. It won't even push it margin-left for 100px. What am I doing wrong? What can I try?

```
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
      <center><img id="image" src="http://www.passionatemedia.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/cropped-top-banner.jpg" width="950"/></center>
      <center><img id="image" src="http://www.passionatemedia.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/navigation.jpg" width="950" /></center>
<!-- end header -->
```

EDIT ADDED CSS

```
#image {
       margin-left:500px;
       display:block;
}
#headerImg {
           margin-left:auto; 
           margin-right:auto;
}
```

STILL NOT WORKING : NEW CODE

HTML/PHP

```
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="headerImg">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/top-banner.jpg" width="950"/>
</div>
<!-- end header -->
```

CSS

```
div.headerImg {
    margin:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:950px;
}
```

Help anyone?

Comment: Those center tags aren't around the code in the FTP. I just mistakenly added them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call Wordpress Stylesheet like this:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

also, this applies to images and scripts in your theme as well, you need to use

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/.......
```

or

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/.......
```

or whatever

EDIT to show code:

Replace this:

```
<center><img id="image" src="http://www.passionatemedia.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/cropped-top-banner.jpg" width="950"/></center>
```

with this:

```
<div class="centerbox"><img src="http://www.passionatemedia.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/cropped-top-banner.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://www.passionatemedia.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/navigation.jpg" alt="" /></div>
```

Now, in CSS:

```
.centerbox{text-align:center}
.centerbox img{width:950px; margin:0 /* <----adjust this to your liking */ auto}
```

Of course you'll need to remove the `/* <----adjust this to your liking */` part, I'm commenting that so you can see it at first sight. Also, don't use IDs unless absolutely necessary. Use classes instead. In your original code, both images had the same ID, which not only is wrong, but has unpredictable results

Comment: it worked but now it's gone and pushed it over too far. can I just add a margin-right:500px; to fix that?

Comment: you need to add your CSS, we have no idea what you have in it

Comment: css has been added in

Comment: Be sure to mark a question as correct if you found it helpful, also feel free to open another question regarding the spacing issue you addressed as it is an entirely new request.

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` elements are *inline*, so they're essentially placed into the HTML document like text. To properly format them, you probably want to put them in a *block* element, such as a `<div>`. That way, you can format them by setting both the left and right margins of the `<div>` or `<div>`s to `auto`.

Generally, try to avoid using the `<center>` element, since it's a deprecated element, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center.